# Camel SMPP issue

Tags: java

I have constructed a camel route like as follows.I am using SMPPSim as Simulator.I am deploying this bundle in apache servicemix 4.4

I am facing the following issue

org.jsmpp.extra.NegativeResponseException: Negative response 0000000b found 
        at org.jsmpp.session.AbstractSession.validateResponse(AbstractSession.java:215)[186:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jsmpp:2.1.0.2] 
        at org.jsmpp.session.AbstractSession.executeSendCommand(AbstractSession.java:271)[186:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jsmpp:2.1.0.2] 
        at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession.submitShortMessage(SMPPSession.java:320)[186:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jsmpp:2.1.0.2] 
        at org.apache.camel.component.smpp.SmppProducer.process(SmppProducer.java:146)[262:org.apache.camel.camel-smpp:2.8.0.fuse-07-15] 
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.AsyncProcessorTypeConverter$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorTypeConverter.java:50)[88:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15] 
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)[88:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:114)[88:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15] 
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:284)[88:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:109)[88:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15] 
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)[88:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:98)[88:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)[88:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15] 
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:69)[88:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15] 
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)[88:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:98)[88:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)[88:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:99)[88:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15] 
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)[88:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:98)[88:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)[88:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15] 
        at org.apache.camel.fabric.FabricTraceProcessor.process(FabricTraceProcessor.java:81)[88:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15] 
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)[88:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:318)[88:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:209)[88:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:45)[88:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)[88:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:304)[88:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15] 
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)[88:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:116)[88:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15]

Answer (score 1):

Error Code 0x0000000B means ESME_RINVDSTADR Invalid destination address. Most likely you are passing a blank value in the destination address field for JSMPP.  I faced this error in the past and the destination address was incorrect.